# Installing GWT SDK in eclipse gives a chain of dependency errors

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt, guava

When I am trying to install GWT SDK for eclipse, it does not install because it requires the Eclipse Maven plugin.
When I try to install the Maven plugin it does not install because it requires the Guava bundle 14.0 or greater.
I don't find Guava bundles greater than 11.00 anywhere on the internet. I can still find the guava libraries up to 17.0. Does any one know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you install the plugin? Is it via eclipse update? What version is your eclipse?

http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.3

I never encountered that problem when updating via Eclipse's Help > Install New Software.

Comment: It worked. I upgraded Eclipse to the 4.3 version and the errors were gone.